# AngularJS run a directive every time the route changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Directive:

```
app.directive('chatAssistant', chatAssistant);

chatAssistant.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state'];

function chatAssistant($rootScope, $state) {
  return {
    link: function() {
      let listener = function() {
        !(function(g, s, q, r, d) {

          r = g[r] = g[r] || function() {
            (r.q = r.q || []).push(arguments);
          };

          d = s.createElement(q);
          q = s.getElementsByTagName(q)[0];
          d.src = '//placeholder.cloudfront.net/tracker.js';
          q.parentNode.insertBefore(d, q);
        })(window, document, 'script', '_gs');

        _gs('GSN-XXXXXX-N');

        if ($state.current.name === 'login' ||
            $state.current.name === 'register' ||
            $state.current.name === 'forgotPassword' ||
            $state.current.name === 'passwordReset') {
          _gs('set', 'chat', {button: false});
        } else {
          _gs('set', 'chat', {button: true});
        }
      };
      $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', listener);
    },
  };
}
```

HTML where it's inserted:

```
<div ui-view
     chat-assistant>
```

This directive simply runs the Javascript code when the DOM or the `<div>` which contains the directive is loaded.  It works great, but I need the directive to basically refresh or re-run everytime the route changes.  Essentially it shows/hides an element based on the route which you can see in the if/else statement.

It currently works, but you have to manually refresh the page for the directive to re-run and get the element to show if you are on a page where it should be shown.

TLDR: I need this directive to re-run everytime the route changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `route.js` file every time route change you need to call function `chatAssistant()`.
by using resolve you can check user is authenticated or not.

Here is simple demo.:-

`route.js`

```
App.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('default');
  $stateProvider.
    .state('userDashboard', {
    url: '/userDashboard',
    title: 'User Dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'userDashboard.html',
    resolve: {
      chatAssistant: chatAssistant
    },
    controller: 'userDashboardController'
  })
});
```

after last outside `App.config` add function to call every route change

```
var chatAssistant = function($rootScope, $state) {
  return {
    link: function() {
      let listener = function() {
        !(function(g, s, q, r, d) {
          r = g[r] = g[r] || function() {
            (r.q = r.q || []).push(arguments);
          };

          d = s.createElement(q);
          q = s.getElementsByTagName(q)[0];
          d.src = '//placeholder.cloudfront.net/tracker.js';
          q.parentNode.insertBefore(d, q);
        })(window, document, 'script', '_gs');
        _gs('GSN-XXXXXX-N');
        if ($state.current.name === 'login' ||
            $state.current.name === 'register' ||
            $state.current.name === 'forgotPassword' ||
            $state.current.name === 'passwordReset') {
          _gs('set', 'chat', {
            button: false
          });
        } else {
          _gs('set', 'chat', {
            button: true
          });
        }
      };
      $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', listener);
    },
  };
}
```